# Which characteristic of an interface allows an ultrasonic sensor to work?

Tags: wave, ultrasound, sensing

Say I have two liquids in a vat and I want to use ultrasonic to determine what height the interface between the two liquids is. What is the actual liquid property that causes the sound waves to reflect at the interface?

For example, say these two liquids have the same index of refraction, or the same molecular density, etc. Would any of these identical properties cause the sound waves to travel past the interface as if the medium was not changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the **speed of sound** in those two liquids, at that frequency, assuming they are immiscible.  If you want it to go straight through the interface, you need liquids with the same speed of sound.

It's basically the same [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law) we learned for light at air/water interfaces.  [Explanation from Penn State University](https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/demos/refract/refract.html).

Comment: I just realized that this question is basically "how to find amount of reflection of sound waves at an interface" and now I'm feeling slightly dumb. Ah well. Thanks!